errer when running minecraft mod
Execution failed for task ':runClient'.

Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --scan to get full insights.

minecraft to load properly

There's not enough here to tell what the error is, best guess with the provided info would be wrong Java version, but IDK what Minecraft requires. Try running it with the --stacktrace option to get a full error message, and edit to include that. Just make sure to remove any personal data you don't want to share.
